# Display and hide text on function trigger

Tags: powershell, user-interface

I'm trying to include a timer to display text when a function is triggered, and to make that text appear for example 2 or 3 seconds.
I've digged a bit but couldn't find my answer, Start-Sleep it's probably only to wait for code execution,here's a snapshot of where the message will appear and should disapear some seconds after [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEjtb.png)

```
function Write-Status {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [String]$Message
    )
    $statusbar1.Text = $Message
}

function sccmrestart {
    Write-Status "Restarting SCCM Client" 
    Start-Sleep 2s

    $Server = $textboxComputername.text
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -ScriptBlock {
        $CurrentLocation = "c:\Windows\CCM"
        $exe = "CcmRestart.exe"
        Start-Process -FilePath "$CurrentLocation\$exe"
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at using:  New-TimeSpan or System.Diagnostics.StopWatch?

Comment: Hello @postanote, i tried simple calculations with New-TimeSpan, but i saw myself into a bigger complex object, allways trying to simplify at the same time. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to clear the status after you set it:

```
function Restart-Sccm {
    Write-Status -Message 'Restarting SCCM Client'
    # swallow process object
    [void](Invoke-Command -ComputerName $textboxComputerName.text -ScriptBlock {
        Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Windows\CCM\CcmRestart.exe'
    })

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
    Write-Status -Message ''
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Maximilian, i was getting the following error Write-Status : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Message' because it is an empty string. I solve this by adding the initial parameter wich is ` Write-Status -Message "Connected to $Server" ` after displaying the message for each function when trigered. Thank anyway :)

Comment: @Cesar_Silva Your question doesn't match your code then.  Empty string still works unless you're using the `ValidateNotNullOrEmpty` attribute.